# Не работает код,что не так?

Tags: python, ооп

```
class SchoolMember:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

class Teacheer(SchoolMember):
    def __int__(self, name, age, Zp):
        SchoolMember.__init__(self, name, age)
        self.Zp = Zp

class Student(SchoolMember):
    def __int__(self, name, age, clss):
        SchoolMember.__init__(self, name, age)
        self.clss = clss

t = Teacheer('Oleg', '35', '40000')
s = Student('Oleg', '5', '4')
print(t)
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что здесь что-то не так?

Comment: Если бы Вы вопросе еще четко сформулировали "что не работает", то помощь пришла бы быстрее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас ошибка в объявлении метода `__init__`.

***Код:***

```py
class SchoolMember:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

class Teacheer(SchoolMember):
    def __init__(self, name, age, Zp):
        SchoolMember.__init__(self, name, age)
        self.Zp = Zp

class Student(SchoolMember):
    def __init__(self, name, age, clss):
        SchoolMember.__init__(self, name, age)
        self.clss = clss

t = Teacheer('Oleg', '35', '40000')
s = Student('Oleg', '5', '4')
print(t)
```

***P. S.:***
*Для вызова конструктора родительского класса лучше использовать `super()`*